# How to count boolean transitions on MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, select, count, boolean, transition

If I have this table:

```
Timestamp            | Raining
---------------------|----------
2016-11-01 8:52:43   | 1
2016-11-01 10:47:39  | 1
2016-11-01 15:19:52  | 0
2016-11-01 15:57:32  | 0
2016-11-03 7:45:01   | 1
2016-11-03 8:10:12   | 0
2016-11-03 9:51:36   | 1
2016-11-03 14:28:42  | 1
2016-11-03 15:14:30  | 0
2016-11-03 18:08:26  | 0
```

Where `0 = not raining` and `1 = raining`

How can I count how many times stopped to rain and how many times begins so?

I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Please provide the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can find last value using session vars, find the difference with current value and take corresponding `count`

```
--stopped =>  1 -> 0, diff = -1
--started =>  0 -> 1, diff = 1

select count(case when diff > 0 then 1 end) rain_started,
 count(case when diff < 0 then 1 end) rain_stopped
from 
(select raining, raining - @lr diff, @lr := raining lr
from (select * from my_table order by timestamp) t,
 (select @lr := null) x
) x;
```

---

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd8b6/2)

Comment: THank you mr @Gurwinder-Singh. But it doesn't work. I think that is something missing after the first "from" clause.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if MySQL will handle this, and I'm guessing this won't be too efficient, but it seems to do the job in SQLServer. Change table/column names as necessary.

```
select RainingNow, Count(*) ChangeCount
FROM (
    Select t1.TheTime, t1.Raining RainingNow, nr.Raining RainingNext
    FROM RainTable t1
    INNER JOIN (
        select TheTime ThisTime, (select min(TheTime) from RainTable where TheTime > rt.TheTime) NextTime
        from RainTable rt
        ) n on t1.TheTime = n.ThisTime
    INNER JOIN RainTable nr on n.NextTime = nr.TheTime
    where t1.Raining <> nr.Raining
) as T2
Group By RainingNow
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select count(*)  from table_name where raining=1;
```

Assuming raining is column name

Comment: If not try raining='1'

Comment: Your select brings me all times that is raining. I just want to count the times that changes from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0.
Thank you anyway.